# Angular- How to add different style to a reusable component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have made a table where user can add data. The input field is a resuable component.
[image]
I want to increase the width and height of the highlighted input field while decreasing the width of the ones inside the table. How do I do it?

This is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvu9mg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.htmlhttps://)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two suggestions.

1. You can set the width of this component to 100% and then control the width of the component from where it is being used. (Only works for width)

`width: 100%;`

2. You can make the height and width as @Input fields of the component and also set up some default values so that you don't need to give the height and width every time you use the component.

**resusable-component.ts**

```
   @Input()
   height = 100;
    
   @Input()
   width= 100;
```

**resusable-component.html**

```
<div 
  [style.width.px]={width} 
  [style.height.px]={height}>
</div>
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<!-- When you want to have a custom height and width-->
<resusable [height]=200 [width]=300></reusable>

<!-- When you want to have a default height and width-->
<resusable></reusable>
```

Comment: this height I should give in the reusable component?

Comment: Yes, In the second point I'm referring to the reusable component .ts and .html file

Comment: I have done that. Check the stackblitz link. You will find `@Input() textSize: string = '1rem';` in the shared component. If I increase that textSize,all the textSizes increases. I don't want that. I only want to increase it in specific case

Comment: Seems you might not understand the purpose of the @Input() functionality, I have edited my answer on how to use it, that way you can have the default the height and width when needed and if you want to change the default values you can provide those values as inputs when using the reusable component.

Comment: Is it possible to make the width dynamic? Check the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvu9mg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) The first `app-shared` has a fixed width. I want to make it dynamic. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, You can wait without providing the width input when you want to use the default value used inside the app-shared component. Incase you want to use a different value you can provide the width value <app-shared [width]="2rem"></app-shared>. I would also suggest you use Numbers instead string values, as i have done in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Jithendra Would you mind giving one upvote to my question. Will be of great help